# parallel builds in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I just installed the "Build Flow" plugin ver 0.7 and i seem to have issues getting it to work. I configured 2 simple jobs (JOB1 and JOB2). Then another jenkins job which i named "parallel_build} that basically calls this job to build them in parallel.

In the "Define build flow using flow DS" section i have the following

parallel ( {buildIJOB1)}, {build(JOB2)} )

when i execute "parallel_build" job, the console output print the following msg and return a build faillure

parallel {

}

Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE

It does not seem to be executing the jobs i intend to run in parallel. The two jobs (JOB1 and JOB2 are pretty simple. All they do is print hello msg.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Jenny

Answer (score 0):

Never mind folks. Upgrading to the latest jenkins version (1.501) from 1.447 fixed the issue. It's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax

```
parallel(
{build("JOB1")},
{build("JOB2")}
)
```